# What is right syntax of testing emptyness of value returned by a function and why?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following recipe to copy files only when sub-makefiles add files to copy.

```
updated_example:
ifneq($(strip $^),)
       cp -rf $^ example && touch updated_example
endif
```

a sub-makefile may add `update_example: file1 file2` etc. but it doesn't work even `echo $^` shows it is not empty.

Weirdly, I changed ifneq to ifeq, the recipe get executed!?

I tried `ifneq("$(strip $^)","")` still doesn't work. It drives me crazy, as I know it has to work somehow. but what exactly is the right syntax?

Comment: `ifeq` and `ifneq` are _MAKE_ operators.  They are expanded as the makefile is read in, not when the recipe is invoked.  So at the time they are parsed, the value of automatic variables like `$^` are not set; those values are only set later, when make is trying to run that recipe.  You have to either use _shell_ if-statements, or else the `if` function as bobbogo shows below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updated_example:
    $(if $^,cp -rf $^ example && touch $@)
```

The recipe for a make rule (i.e., the bunch of shell commands) is stored as a single recursively expanded macro. When *make* decides it has to re-build a target, it

- Expands said macro
- Passes each line in the expansion one at a time to a shell invocation

In your version, the `ifneq` is expanded as *make* is reading the Makefile, just as it's wondering what to put into the macro representing the recipe. At this point `$^` does not exist. In my formulation, I use an `$(if ...)` which sits inside the shell recipe. It is expanded only when *make* starts building *updated_example*, at which point `$^` has appropriate value.

Comment: thanks, but I would like to know what is the right way to test the value returned by a function, e.g. $(strip xxx).

Comment: Functions munge text and return the munged text. In things like `$(if ...)`, `$(and ...)`, `$(or ...)` etc. a true is any non-empty text. (There are a few caveats, but you won't go far wrong with this definition.)